# How to retrieve the data from the list in django templates through request

Tags: python, html, django-views, django-templates

I'm newly learning django. I'm trying to learn django by making todo app. I've created a view having template in which I'm showing a list of items to the user using for loop. I've also created a link for each item.Now I want to access the item that user clicked and I should display all details related to that item, for that I've created another view.But the problem is I'm not getting how to access that. Here's my code.

- views.py

```
 def display_user_tasks(request):
      name = request.user
      task_list = Task.objects.filter(user=User.objects.get(username=request.user.username))
       context = {
        'name': name,
        'task_list': task_list,
        }
       return render(request, 'todo/task_list.html', context) 

def about_tasks(request):
    name = request.user
    task = request.task
    context = {
        'task': task,
        'name': name,
    }
    return render(request, 'todo/about_tasks.html', context)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Task List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
{% if task_list %}
    <p> Hello {{ name }} Here are your tasks</p>

   {% for task in task_list %}
    
        {{ forloop.counter }}
        <a href="about_tasks"> {{ task }}</a> <br>

   {% endfor %}

{% else %}
       <p> No tasks yet </p>
{% endif %}
    <br>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='task-form'">Add task</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've just tried to display whether the task which user clicked is displaying or not.

- about_task.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>About tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ name }}<br>
{{ task }}
  <p> You will see about your tasks here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer for my problem. I can send the clicked item as parameter in urls. So, I did it and this parameter takes the value when I use the name the respective url.